# Different authorzations depending on binding

Tags: asp.net, iis, binding, authorization, hostname

If I had one website that had multiple bindings - for example;

```
demosite.com
demosite.net
```

Would it be possible to use Authorization rules to
Allow anonymous users access on demosite.com
Only allow authenticated users access on demosite.net

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Yes it's entirely possible. You can use the authorise attribute on the project you publish to one site and omit that while publishing to second site. If you want something more specific, then add the details to your question